# Max height on columns

Tags: css

Is it possible to automatically start a new columns after a given height? I know I can do `.col {max-height: <maxlength>}`, but I wouldn't know if the text were too long and overflow. `overflow-y` would be awkward, and unwanted.

ATTEMPT #1

css:

```
.columns
{
    columns: 2;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="columns">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei an quas quando, ne qui
equidem luptatum, nam ei debet feugait appareat. Te sed denique fastidii 
persequeris. Ius an soleat nonumes, te nec nominavi persecuti, nec ut tation
offendit eloquentiam. Vix ne omnes vulputate, mea sumo mundi homero te,
ludus meliore disputando his ex.
</div>
```

Output:

col1col1col1 col1col1 col2col2 col2col2col2 \
col1col1 col1col1col1 col2 col2col2col2col2  |>`too long :(`
col1col1col1 col1col1 col2col2 col2col2col2  |
col1col1 col1col1col1 col2 col2col2col2col2  |
col1col1col1 col1col1 col2col2 col2col2col2  |
col1col1 col1col1col1 col2 col2col2col2col2  |
col1col1col1 col1col1 col2col2 col2col2col2  |
col1col1 col1col1col1 col2 col2col2col2col2  /
col1col1 col1col1col1 col2

ATTEMPT #2

css:

```
.columns
{
    columns: 2;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="columns">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei an quas quando, ne qui
equidem luptatum, nam ei debet feugait appareat. Te sed denique fastidii 
persequeris. Ius an soleat nonumes, te nec nominavi persecuti, nec ut tation
offendit eloquentiam. Vix ne omnes vulputate, mea sumo mundi homero te,
ludus meliore disputando his ex.
</div>
```

Output:

col1col1col1 col1col1 col2col2 col2col2col2 col3col3 col3col3col3 col4col4col4 col4col4
col1col1 col1col1col1 col2 col2col2col2col2 col3 col3col3col3col3 col4col4col4col4 col4
col1col1col1 col1col1 col2col2 col2col2col2 col3 col3col3col3col3 col4col4col4col4 col4
col1col1 col1col1col1 col2 col2col2col2col2 col3 col3col3col3col3 col4col4col4col4 col4

DESIRED OUTPUT:
(start a new column automatically once it has reached a specified height
and on a new line every second column)

col1col1col1 col1col1 col2col2 col2col2col2 \
col1col1 col1col1col1 col2 col2col2col2col2  |>`specified height`
col1col1col1 col1col1 col2col2 col2col2col2  |
col1col1 col1col1col1 col2 col2col2col2col2 /

col3col3 col3col3col3 col4col4col4 col4col4
col3 col3col3col3col3 col4col4col4col4 col4
col3col3 col3col3col3 col4col4col4 col4col4
col3 col3col3col3col3 col4col4col4col4 col4

col5col5col5col5 col5
col5col5col5col5

Comment: Can you post your code and clarify the question?

Comment: @ZimSystem Better?

Comment: So you want to create a new column after lets say 200 characters from that text?

Comment: Maybe a combination of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts and some JS?

Comment: @Nicholas I was thinking once the length of a column reaches a certain height, but after a given number of characters would probably suffice.

Comment: I think what @AmericanSlime wrote might be your solution.